# gcc - undefined reference to `libusb_init'

Tags: c, gcc, libusb, libusb-1.0

I'm trying to compile a piece of code which uses libusb:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
    libusb_context *context = NULL;
    int rc = 0;

    rc = libusb_init(&context);
    assert(rc == 0);

    libusb_exit(context);
    return 0;
}
```

Upon compiling with `gcc -lusb -lusb-1.0 sample.c -o sample` the following errors emerge:

```
/tmp/ccr65JBT.o: In function `main':
sample.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `libusb_init'
sample.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To make sure libusb is availible on my system:

```
raven@enforcer:~/sample$ pkg-config --libs libusb-1.0
-lusb-1.0
raven@enforcer:~/sample$ pkg-config --libs libusb
-lusb
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with gcc 7.3.0-16ubuntu3, how to fix?

Comment: try putting the libs after your .c file in the command line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74634657/5432351

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working by appending the flags after the .c: `gcc sample.c -o sample -lusb -lusb-1.0`

Autotools: `sample_LDADD` instead of `sample_LDFLAGS`

Thanks to Felix Palmen.

Comment: rough explanation: a linker typically works by holding a list of unresolved symbols and looking to resolve them from the object files (or archives or libraries) it encounters later ... and GCC lets the linker process the object files in the order they appear on the initial command line.